# How do you create a completely blank Brightcove player template, with no controls?

Tags: javascript, xml, html5-video, brightcove

I'm trying to load up a Brightcove video which has absolutely no controls when the HTML5 version loads on iPads (e.g: play/pause, progress bar, volume) and just plays the video. This video will then be controlled with buttons on the page via the Smart Player API. I have tried creating a very blank template using the BEML markup like below, and it hides the controls in the flash player but doesn't effect the HTML5 player, am I missing anything here?

```
<Runtime>
  <Theme name="Deluxe" style="Dark"/>
  <Layout>
    <ChromelessVideoPlayer id="videoPlayer" useOverlayMenu="false" video="{videoList.selectedItem}" theme="">
      <ChromelessControls boxType="vbox" visible="false" vAlign="bottom">
      </ChromelessControls>
    </ChromelessVideoPlayer>
  </Layout>
</Runtime>
```

I thought there might be some methods in the **Javascript Smart Player API** but I can't seem to find them, does anything like `hideVideoControls` or something along those lines exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brightcove has an article that I think accomplishes what you want.

http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/solutions/overlay-message-3.html